# How to bypaas CSP or ctrl+f5 in Puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to load a page which is loading a cross domain iframe (recaptcha)

Sometimes for random reason the page gets an error of CSP
And the only thing that helps to remove it is manually CTRl+f5
I've tried various methods of removing the cache with the chrome dev api , and reload both with

```
page.reload()
```

And page evaluate

Without sucess (seems like the page keeps loading for cache / new requests to it not being made)

I've also tried to set await bypassCSP(true)
And it doesn't help eaither

Can anyone recommend something else to try?

Code i've tried with F5+Ctrl and didn't work:

```
async function main() {
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
    let browser2 = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
    let page2 = await browser2.newPage();
    await page2.goto("http://google.com/");
    await page2.keyboard.down('Control');
    await page2.keyboard.press('F5');
    await page2.keyboard.up('Control');
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you kindly use keyboard ?

```
    await page.goto("https://www.google.com/", {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });

    await page.waitFor(3000);

    await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
    await page.reload({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
```

Regards

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to work, I did some research and it seems like chrome shortcuts doesn't work :( tell me if I'm wrong please

Comment: I just tried on my side and it worked. Can you kindly share more code ?

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't working on my side even with the simplest code , just updated the question

Comment: it worked with these code on my side 
        await page.waitForSelector("[name='login[username]");
 await page.type("[name='login[username]']", "talenttop044@gmail.com");
 await page.waitForSelector("[name='login[password]");
 await page.type("[name='login[password]']", "D&6^XM#8<]Vn_mjh");

 await page2.keyboard.down('Control');
    await page2.keyboard.press('F5');
    await page2.keyboard.up('Control');

Comment: on which url did it work? can't get it work on google (as there is no login[password] and both for twitter login page

Comment: const page = await browser.newPage();
 page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(100000);
 await page.goto("https://www.markedbyteachers.com/customer/account/login/referer/aHR0cDovL3d3dy5tYXJrZWRieXRlYWNoZXJzLmNvbS8,/", {
  waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
 });

Comment: also if you kindly upvote my commend ? I think that should be work. I tried on google but google does not work. It seems to be we need to do something on the page before reload

Comment: it doesn't seem to work :( it would be great if you could paste the code into jsfiddle

Comment: I don't know who you are but lets fix together this problem. Can you share me jsfiddle url ?  I have free time now, will try to fix this together with you.

Comment: I am saving now, it worked when I test again just before

Comment: seems like it didn't save , try this https://jsfiddle.net/xajfqg6y/#&togetherjs=Lg4CJ8PiAg

Comment: It;s not working on my side too. Let me find another solution.

Comment: I changed the code , await page.goto("https://www.google.com/", {
  waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
 });

 await page.waitFor(3000);

 await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
 await page.reload({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});
Please check with this

Comment: doesn't seem so :(

Comment: Did you try with changed code ?
 await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
 await page.reload({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});

Comment: await page.goto("https://www.google.com/", {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2'
    });

    await page.waitFor(3000);

    await page.setCacheEnabled(false);
    await page.reload({waitUntil: 'networkidle2'});


This surely works, I tested much times.